# DECIMATION LOGIC

Tags: math, logic

Is it possible to decimate a thousand items till there is only one left and if so how many decimation cycles are required? By decimate, I mean remove only a tenth and leave the rest, e.g, 1st cycle: 1000 - 900 (remove a tenth: 100)
                               2nd cycle: 900 - 810 (remove a tenth: 90)

Comment: Maybe ask that at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)

Comment: I doubt they will let me now that I have posted it here

Comment: @jhhoff02 Please be noted that this question is likely off-topic for [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/). [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) is for research level math questions only. Please see [their help center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the numerical type you use.
If you use floating point numbers, you will eventually reach a value smaller than `1` (not exactly though, as the output of the following java program shows):

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    double val = 1000;
    while (val > 1) {
      val -= val/10;
      i++;
      System.out.println("val = " + val + " in iteration " + i);
    }
  }
}
```

Excerpt from the output:

```
val = 900.0 in iteration 1
val = 810.0 in iteration 2
val = 729.0 in iteration 3
...
val = 1.0611166119964726 in iteration 65
val = 0.9550049507968253 in iteration 66
```

If you use an integer type, will won't reach `1`, because as soon as `val == 9`, it won't get any smaller, as the divison result is `0`. I added a check to catch that condition to prevent an endless loop.

Let's have a look:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    int val = 1000;
    while (val > 1) {
      int subtract = val/10;
      if (subtract == 0) {
        System.out.println("subtracted value is 0 for value " + val + " at iteration " + i);
        break;
      }
      val -= subtract;
      i++;
      System.out.println("val = " + val + " in iteration " + i);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
val = 900 in iteration 1
val = 810 in iteration 2
...
val = 10 in iteration 49
val = 9 in iteration 50
value 9 repeats at iteration 50
```